# Django annotate with

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

How can I use `average_ndvi` and `field_count` variables into annotate, I need to change `0.14` to `average_ndvi` and  `5` to `field_count`.

```
 commune = (
        Commune.objects.annotate(
            year=SearchVector("field__fieldattribute__date__year"),
            month=SearchVector(Cast("field__fieldattribute__date__month", CharField())),
            size=Sum(F("field__fieldattribute__planted_area")),
            average_ndvi=Avg(F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi")),
            field_count=Count("field"),
            standart_deviation=Sum(
                ((F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi") - 0.14) ** 2) / 5,
                output_field=FloatField(),
            ),
        )
        .filter(year=year, month=str(month))
        .only("id", "name")
    )
```

models.py

```
class Region(models.Model):
    geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Commune(models.Model):
    geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)


class CommuneAttribute(models.Model):
    commune = models.ForeignKey(Commune, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    ndvi = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(NDVI_MIN), MaxValueValidator(NDVI_MAX)],
    )
    ndmi = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(NDMI_MIN), MaxValueValidator(NDMI_MAX)],
    )
    average_yield = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    planted_area = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    crop_risk = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    available_agriculture_land = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


class Field(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    farm = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    farm_leader = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True)
    commune = models.ForeignKey(Commune, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

class FieldAttribute(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    ndvi = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(NDVI_MIN), MaxValueValidator(NDVI_MAX)],
    )
    ndmi = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(NDMI_MIN), MaxValueValidator(NDMI_MAX)],
    )
    harvest_forecast = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    planted_area = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    crop_risk = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crop = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    average_yield = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply put `standart_deviation` to a separate, second `annotate` call. There you will be able to refer to fields added by the first `annotate` call:

```
 commune = (
        Commune.objects.annotate(
            year=SearchVector("field__fieldattribute__date__year"),
            month=SearchVector(Cast("field__fieldattribute__date__month", CharField())),
            size=Sum(F("field__fieldattribute__planted_area")),
            average_ndvi=Avg(F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi")),
            field_count=Count("field"),
        ).annotate(
            standart_deviation=Sum(
                ((F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi") - F("average_ndvi")) ** 2) / F("field_count"),
                output_field=FloatField(),
            ),
        )
        .filter(year=year, month=str(month))
        .only("id", "name")
    )
```

Comment: i tryed but get error 

"Cannot compute Sum('<CombinedExpression: F(field__fieldattribute__ndvi) - F(average_ndvi) ^ Value(2) / F(field_count)>'): '<CombinedExpression: F(field__fieldattribute__ndvi) - F(average_ndvi) ^ Value(2) / F(field_count)>' is an aggregate"

Comment: As I understand, it says that it can't compute an aggregate (Sum), because some of its inputs  are already aggregates (`average_ndvi` is `Avg`, and `field_count` is `Count`). Which kind of makes sense. In your place, I would review the purpose of this query and try to write the SQL query producing the desired result. With SQL, I would return to Django and try to reconstruct the query with Django ORM (falling back to raw SQL when/if necessary)

Comment: как можно это обойти?

Comment: к сожаление sql плохо знаю особенно с такими сложными запросами, смысл в том что у коммун есть много полей  и мне нужно аннотировать поле standart_deviation которое равно сумме standart_deviation для каждого поля, standart_deviation = field_attribute - Avg(field_attribute) / Count(commune_field)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `0.14` to `Avg(F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi"))` and `5` to `Count("field")` because aggregated values access on **HAVING** clause.
I think it will work.

```
commune = (
        Commune.objects.annotate(
            year=SearchVector("field__fieldattribute__date__year"),
            month=SearchVector(Cast("field__fieldattribute__date__month", CharField())),
            size=Sum(F("field__fieldattribute__planted_area")),
            average_ndvi=Avg(F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi")),
            field_count=Count("field"),
            standart_deviation=Sum(
                ((F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi") - Avg(F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi"))) ** 2) / Count("field"),
                output_field=FloatField(),
            ),
        )
        .filter(year=year, month=str(month))
        .only("id", "name")
    )
```

Comment: i get error "Cannot compute Sum is an aggregate"

Comment: Yes it will give error because we use Avg() in Sum() function. Please share model code.

Comment: i resolve this problem use Subquery but it takes a lot of time.




```annotate(
            average_ndmi=Subquery(
                Field.objects.filter(commune_id=OuterRef("pk"))
                .values("commune_id")
                .annotate(ndmi_avg=Avg("fieldattribute__ndmi"))
                .values("ndmi_avg"),
                output_field=FloatField(),
            )
        )```

Comment: you can use seperate query to calculate ```Avg(F("field__fieldattribute__ndvi")) ``` and ```Count("field")``` and use that value in main query.

Comment: No. I need AVG for each region

Comment: share model code and first try raw SQL query then we can try using ORM.

Comment: i updated title